# Keeping a virtual keyboard focused

Tags: javascript, html

I've got virtual keyboard I'm using (Touch Kiosk Keyboard) which stays up while clicked into a textbox. I've made the below function to go back to the textbox when blurred. the keyboard comes up temproarily but then disappears. I wish I knew what this keyboard was looking for, any ideas of what I can try to keep that focus there?

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
 
 
  <input class="full-width" type="text" id="textbox" name="texbox" onblur="myFunction()"/>
  <script>var _this = this;
                function myFunction() {
                    _this.textbox.focus();
                   
                } </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: you dont need jquery for `.focus()`

Comment: Do you have any errors on the console?

Comment: @spadletskys no console errors. The function is working, the textbox keeps the cursor in it. When I type on my physical keyboard it appears in there, but the virtual keyboard does not stay up. I'm trying various things to see if maybe the virtual keyboard is looking for something besides .focus(), but I'm fairly new to js so I'm looking for ideas haha. I'm trying .click() as we speak

Comment: @spadletskys actually there's an uncaught type error at the getAttribute("_originalType"); line. is it timing out?


`function vk_evt_input_blur() {`
`  virtualKeyboardChromeExtension_generate_onchange();`
  `virtualKeyboardChromeExtensionClickedElem.type =` `virtualKeyboardChromeExtensionClickedElem.getAttribute("_originalType");`
 `virtualKeyboardChromeExtensionClickedElem = undefined;`
`virtualKeyboardChromeExtensionCloseTimer = setTimeout(function () {`
   `virtualKeyboardChromeExtension_click('Close');`
`}, 1000);`
`}`

Comment: is the virtaul keboard yours? or is it a library or an app etc.???

Comment: @spadletskys unfortunately it's a chrome extension called Touch Kiosk Keyboard. I'm experimenting with attempting to set that variable in `myFunction()`

Comment: What variable do you want? The `_originalType` variable?

Comment: @spadletskys I'm pretty sure it's looking for "text". That's at least what's in the developer console when I inspect my textbox element!

Comment: I got something that works @spadletskys. it was happening too fast for the keyboard js, so the keyboard was still in the middle of closing.
<br/>
var _this = this; <br/>
   <br/>
                async function myFunction() { <br/>
                    
function sleep(duration) { <br/>
 return new Promise(resolve => { <br/>
  setTimeout(() => { <br/>
   resolve() <br/>
  }, duration * 250) <br/>
 }) <br/>
}; <br/>
await sleep(1); <br/>
<br/>
                   _this.textbox.focus(); <br/>
    _this.textbox.setAttribute("_originaltype", "text"); <br/>
                }